# AAPT: error: resource android:attr/popupPromptView is private

Tags: android

I am using `actionbarsherlock` library in my android app and I am using one of its `style` attribute with the name of `popupPromptView` but when I try to generate the `apk` for my app, it gives me this error:

```
C:\Users\My Username\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\fa481916e694bf5a6973eb98ad535c2d\jetified-actionbarsherlock-4.4.0\res\values\values.xml:268:5-296:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/popupPromptView is private.
```

I tried going to this `values.xml` file and comment out this style attribute but when I try to generate the `apk` again, that line which I commented comes back again. I don't know what's wrong. I have even tried deleting the `cache` folder of `.gradle` but still no luck.

Comment: can you please post the error log, need more information.

Comment: @Nakul I have already posted the entire error log.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

You can solve downloading Sherlock as a module itself to compile together with your project (I imported the Sherlock modules from a Eclipse project) instead of using a library reference

In this way you can remove that line in a definitive way

Comment: and how do we get these modules ?
Any url or a procedure with android studio ?

Comment: I did get the sherlock module on their official website but don't know how to add it to the project...

Answer (score 0):

it made my day
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2

In previous versions of AAPT, the compiler would silently ignore foregroundInsidePadding attributes when you define it with the android namespace. When using AAPT2, the compiler catches this early and throws the following build error:

Error: (...) resource android:attr/foregroundInsidePadding is private
To resolve this issue, simply replace android:foregroundInsidePadding with foregroundInsidePadding.